# Problema con Componente COM

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms

Alguien me podría orientar respecto a un problema con un componente COM en c#, esto para adjuntarlo a un Form, con el framework .NET, el COM en cuestión es El Windows Media Player(WMP), he tratado de realizar un reproductor de video, la función de agregar a lista, abrir archivos todo bien, pero este al intentar reproducirlos no lo hace y mas bien me cierra el programa, no he programado ninguna función para que cuando se reproduzca algo se cierre, en depuración me sale un error que corresponde a esto: **termino con código -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'**.

He intentado probar el programa en diferentes computadoras, pero es el mismo problema, este no reproduce, simplemente se cierra.

Cualquier ayuda será, bienvenida.

Adjunto código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string[] paths, files;

        private void track_list_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                player.URL = paths[track_list.SelectedIndex];

                player.Ctlcontrols.play();

                lbl_msg.Text = "Playing...";

                timer1.Start();

                trackBar1.Value = 15;

                lbl_volume.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";

            }
            catch (AccessViolationException av)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("An error occured\nTechnical error: {0}"), av.Message);
            }




        }


        private void btn_play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Ctlcontrols.play();

            lbl_msg.Text = "Playing...";
        }

        private void btn_pause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Ctlcontrols.pause();

            lbl_msg.Text = "Pause";
        }

        private void btn_stop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.Ctlcontrols.stop();

            lbl_msg.Text = "Stop";
        }

        private void btn_next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (track_list.SelectedIndex < track_list.Items.Count - 1)

            {

                track_list.SelectedIndex = track_list.SelectedIndex + 1;

            }
        }

        private void btn_prev_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (track_list.SelectedIndex > 0)

            {

                track_list.SelectedIndex = track_list.SelectedIndex - 1;

            }
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (player.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)

            {

                progressBar1.Maximum = (int)player.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.duration;

                progressBar1.Value = (int)player.Ctlcontrols.currentPosition;



            }

            lbl_track_start.Text = player.Ctlcontrols.currentPositionString;

            lbl_track_end.Text = player.Ctlcontrols.currentItem.durationString.ToString();
        }

        private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            player.settings.volume = trackBar1.Value;

            lbl_volume.Text = trackBar1.Value.ToString() + "%";
        }

        private void btn_open_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Multiselect = true;

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)

            {

                files = ofd.SafeFileNames;

                paths = ofd.FileNames;

                for (int x = 0; x < files.Length; x++)

                {

                    track_list.Items.Add(files[x]);

                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: podra ser una incompatibilidad entre algo de 32 bits y algo de 64?

Comment: Es curioso, por qué, la primera prueba dió, luego reinicie la PC y el programa dejo de funcionar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que el antivirus que tengas instalado a detectado el System.Threading.Tasks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
' Comenta y Prueba de Nuevo using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

Comment: A mi me paso algo parecido y tuve que comentar algo de código huérfano que tenia relación con el System.Threading